# How to import models.py from one app to another models.py in another app?

Tags: python, django

I am making a web app that is similar to google classroom in django. I am coding this in repl.it, so i can't see the main application. I have two apps and mysite folder.

One app is room and another is users
I am trying to import a class from `models.py` that is in the room app to the `models.py` in the users app
But when I do `from room.models import Course`, I get an error
This is the screenshot for my whole directory, code and error.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django ImportError: cannot import name 'ReporterProfile' from partially initialized module 'accounts.models' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100550/django-importerror-cannot-import-name-reporterprofile-from-partially-initiali)

Comment: In future, please provide trace of errors and code in text format rather than posting image. It will be helpful for the ones who one want to help you. Cheers !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove import and try below in course_owned field

```
courses_owned = models.ManyToManyField(to='room.Course',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "most likely due to circular import" which means you import usermodel and it imports usermodel so: usermodel > roommodel > usermodel > roommodel... it goes like this. I believe this is the problem.